# knitr: LaTex Longtable spanning several pages with word continued at bottom and caption appears only once in list of tables

Tags: longtable, knitr, sweave, rnw

I want to have `longtable` spanning several pages with word continued at right bottom of the table and its caption appearing only one in the list of tables using `knitr`. Below is my MWE in `.Rnw` format. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables



<< label=LongTable, results='asis', echo = FALSE >>=
library(xtable)
set.seed(12345)
MatrixData <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)

print(
  xtable(
      x = MatrixData
    , caption = "Example of longtable spanning several pages"
    , label = "tab:MatrixData"
    , align = c("l|", rep("r", ncol(MatrixData)))
    , digits = c(rep(3, ncol(MatrixData)+1))
  )

  , table.placement = "H"
  , caption.placement = "top"
  , include.rownames = TRUE
  , include.colnames = TRUE
  , size = "small"
  , tabular.environment = 'longtable'
  , floating = FALSE
  , add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),command = "\\hline \\endhead ")
)
@

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

<< label=LongTable, results='asis', echo = FALSE >>=
library(xtable)
set.seed(12345)
MatrixData <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)

print(
  xtable(
      x = MatrixData
    , caption = "Example of longtable spanning several pages"
    #, label = "tab:MatrixData"
    , align = c("l|", rep("r", ncol(MatrixData)))
    , digits = c(rep(3, ncol(MatrixData)+1))
  )

  , table.placement = "H"
  , caption.placement = "top"
  , include.rownames = TRUE
  , include.colnames = TRUE
  , size = "small"
  , tabular.environment = 'longtable'
  , floating = FALSE
  , add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),command = 
                        paste("\\hline  \\endfirsthead"  ,                          # First caption
                                "\\caption[]{Example of longtable spanning several pages} \\label{tab:MatrixData} \\\\ \\hline", # Additional captions
                                paste("&", 1:ncol(MatrixData),collapse=" "),                              # Column names
                                "\\\\ \\hline ",
                                "\\endhead", 
                                "\\hline \\multicolumn{11}{r}{\\textit{Continued}} \\                    
                                 \\endfoot
                                 \\endlastfoot",collapse=" ")))
@

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer doesn't repeat the header row. Any idea.

Comment: Also included the word Continued in the footer now

Comment: (+1) Great. But still header row is not repeated on each page.

Comment: I didn't realise that the names of the columns were removed. The edited code should work but this is probably not the easiest solution.

Comment: Excellent. One more thing. Did you see the last page carefully. On last page vertical line is off the table. Any idea about this to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @user1570707 for your answer. I'll keep this question open for a while to have any other answer. Please also see me edits.

Comment: You are welcome! The problem with the vertical line on the last page is caused by the label. xtable puts the label after the table but before \end{longtable}. An alternative is to not define label and to instead add the \label to the add.to.row command, as described above.